# Re-creating tibbles within purrr::map

Tags: r, purrr

I want to use map to apply a function to each column of a tibble.
However, I don't want the tibble columns to be simplified.
I could deal with that by re-creating tibbles with one column using `imap`.
However, how do I do that?

Let's use a super-simple function called `test` to see if it works.

Default behavior: columns simplified to vectors:

```
test<-function(data){
  data
}

tibble(v1=1:20,v2=100:119) %>% map(test)
$v1
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

$v2
 [1] 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119
```

This can't work because the names need to be quoted:

```
tibble(v1=1:20,v2=100:119) %>% imap(~test(tibble(.y=.x))) %>% str
List of 2
 $ v1: tibble [20 x 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ .y: int [1:20] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ v2: tibble [20 x 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  ..$ .y: int [1:20] 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 ...
```

So why does this not work?

```
tibble(v1=1:20,v2=100:119) %>% imap(~test(tibble(!!!(.y)=.x)))
Error: unexpected '=' in "tibble(v1=1:20,v2=100:119) %>% imap(~test(tibble(!!!(.y)="
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change the `=` to assignment operator (`:=`) and evaluate (`!!`) the `.`y on the lhs of `:=`

```
library(tibble)
library(purrr)
out <- tibble(v1=1:20,v2=100:119) %>% 
        imap( ~ test(tibble(!!.y := .x)))
```

-output

```
str(out)
#List of 2
# $ v1: tibble [20 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#  ..$ v1: int [1:20] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
# $ v2: tibble [20 × 1] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
#  ..$ v2: int [1:20] 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setNames` :

```
tibble::tibble(v1=1:20,v2=100:119) %>% purrr::imap(~test(.x) %>% setNames(.y))

#$v1
# A tibble: 20 x 1
#      v1
#   <int>
# 1     1
# 2     2
# 3     3
# 4     4
# 5     5
#...
#...

#$v2
# A tibble: 20 x 1
#      v2
#   <int>
# 1   100
# 2   101
# 3   102
# 4   103
# 5   104
# 6   105
#...
#...
```

Comment: Thanks. However, if `test()` requires its input to be a tibble (instead of a vector), this would not help.

Comment: if `test()` requires input to be tibble then both `imap` or `map` would not help since both of them would convert the column to vector. I don't think `setNames` would be an issue here.

Comment: Ok..then I don't exactly understand your comment. Maybe if you could show what output are you expecting or provide an example where my answer fails I can update my answer.

Comment: Use the (admittedly) very contrived function `test<-function(data){glue::glue("Average: {colMeans(data)} in variable variable called {colnames(data)[1]}")}` - akrun's code will work without error.

Comment: @Inferrator That is because in his answer tibble is created explicitly. If you change my answer to `tibble::tibble(v1=1:20,v2=100:119) %>% purrr::imap(~test(tibble(.x) %>% setNames(.y)))` it will work similarly.